# Pagination based on the result from dependent drop list

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I am looking for a tutorial on pagination that only associates with the dependent drop list.  In other words, If I made a selection from a dependent drop list with items, {Beavers, Cubs, Scouts, Venturers, Rovers and Leaders}. It will display the associated records and I was able to do that with ajax.  However, some of those items have more than 100 records, and I would like to add pagination based on what was selected and can only find the tutorial that has drop list based of total number of record, example {50, 100, 250, 500, 5000 etc}

I have been searching using, 
pagination based on the result from a dependent drop list ,
dependent drop list with pagination, 
dynamic pagination with a drop list etc

with PHP, MySQL, js and ajax with no success.  I am fairly new with this and a tutorial will help me understand better,  Can anyone tell me what to look for? thanks

code for AdminPanelFrontEnd.php

```
    <?php

        require_once('includes/header.php'); 
        require_once('includes/connection.php');

        if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM members";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        }
        else
        {
            header("location:AdminPanelFrontEnd.php");
        }

    ?>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    function load_data(SectionID)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AdminPanelBackEnd.php",
            data: 'SectionID=' + SectionID,
            success: function(data){
                $("#details").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-striped bg-info text-white" id="details" >

    <tr>
        <a href="AddMemberFrontEnd.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary mb-3 float-left">Add Member</a>  

        <div class="form-inline float-left ml-1">
            <select class="form-control mb-2" id="section" onChange="load_data(this.value);">
                <option value="null">Select Section</option>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM sections ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);   
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                       { 
                ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo $row["SectionID"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["SectionName"]; ?> </option>
                <?php    
                       }
                ?>                   
            </select>
        </div> 
    </tr>

    <tr class="bg-info text-white">                           
        <td>Member Name</td>                    
        <td>Member Email</td>
        <td>Member Contact</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

code for AdminPanelBackEnd.php

```
<?php 

require_once('includes/connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM sections, members WHERE 
sections.SectionID ='".$_POST["SectionID"]."' AND 
sections.SectionID = members.SectionID ORDER BY MemberName
";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

?>
    <table class="text-center bg-info text-white">    
        <tr>                           
            <td>Member Name</td>                    
            <td>Member Email</td>
            <td>Member Contact</td>
        </tr> 
        <?php 
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $Member = $row['MemberName'];
                $MemberEmail= $row['Email'];  
                $MemberContact = $row['Contact'];                                                 
        ?>

        <tr class="bg-light text-dark">
            <td><?php echo $Member ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $MemberEmail ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $MemberContact ?></td>            
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you said, you already did the ajax, so the query string should be included in the paging navigation.
The link for next page should look like `?page=2&category=some_id`
The ajax call will replace the whole content and the navigation.

There are libraries supporting that on every framework.

Comment: I have pasted the code, I am guessing I need to redo the ajax?

Comment: Adjusted code here would be welcome plus some links to useful libraries.